# Why custom RuntimeExceptions need to inherit directly from RuntimeException?

Tags: java, exception, inheritance, runtimeexception

I try to create a base RuntimeException class:

```
BaseRuntimeException extends RuntimeException
```

with some additional functionality such as i18n. From that base class I want to create one class per type of RuntimeException. For ex.,

```
public class SetterWithNullPointerException extends BaseRuntimeException
```

However, I am getting this compile error wherever I throw a `SetterWithNullPointerException`

```
Unhandled exception type SetterWithNullPointerException
```

It is like by not having RuntimeException being the direct superclass of `SetterWithNullPointerException`, I lose the unchecked exception properties of RuntimeException. (Easily checked if I make `SetterWithNullPointerException` inherit directly from `RuntimeExeption`)

My question is... is there anyway around this? Do I have to make something special on `BaseRuntimeException`to make its children inherit the unchecked exception properties?

Thanks a lot!
Manu

Comment: The error must be somewhere else. You can certainly indirectly extend RuntimeException. `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` extends `IndexOutOfBoundsException` extends `RuntimeException`.

Comment: Many unchecked Exceptions don't inherit directly from Error or RuntimeException.

Comment: Can you show us some code, please?

Comment: Post your custom Exception code here. Issue is in your code.

Comment: You were right guys, issue was in my code. As soon as I was going to post the code for you I realised... I'll post an answer with the fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry for all the noise. The comments under this answer are correct. There was nothing wrong on what I was doing. You can extend as many times as you want RuntimeException.

My IDE must have played a trick on me. Where there were compiler errors before, there are none now. 
Kids, before coming to SO, do a "Project Clean" when you think the errors you are seeing don't make any sense...

Apologies again.

Comment: That wouldn't cause this problem. The compiler already does that automatically.

Comment: I swear that if I comment those two constructors I get the compile error mentioned in the OP on every part of the code where I do: throw new SetterWithNullPointerException()

Comment: @EJP Is it possible that it is a problem, that he made `BaseRuntimeException` abstract? - EDIT: Nope, just tried that.

Comment: @manubot I just set up a little project, that has nothing more than 2 Exception classes, one abstract extending RuntimeException and the other extending the first. Complete empty class bodies, both. Could instanciate and throw the latter without any compiler error.